# How to perform math operations with OpenCV Matrix and a point-like value in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, opencv

I want to scale a contour in OpenCV.js. I have a valid contour in cnt variable of type cv.Mat (verified it by using drawContours).

I found a function in Python that does everything I need but I have problems converting it to Javascript.

Python version:

```
def scale_contour(cnt, scale):
    M = cv2.moments(cnt)
    cx = int(M['m10']/M['m00'])
    cy = int(M['m01']/M['m00'])

    cnt_norm = cnt - [cx, cy]
    cnt_scaled = cnt_norm * scale
    cnt_scaled = cnt_scaled + [cx, cy]
    cnt_scaled = cnt_scaled.astype(np.int32)

    return cnt_scaled
```

Here's what I started for Javascript:

```
function scaleContour(cnt, scale) {
    console.log("cnt", cnt.data32S, cnt.rows, cnt.cols, cnt.type());

    const M = cv.moments(cnt);
    const cx = M['m10']/M['m00'];
    const cy = M['m01']/M['m00'];
    const offset = [Math.ceil(cx), Math.ceil(cy)];
    console.log("Offset", offset);

    // cannot use convenient Python arithmetics here,
    // have to call functions
    // although technically we have 1 row 2 cols for a point, but the cnt type is 2-channel CV_32SC2 (12)
    // therefore keeping the size 1,1 and leave the second dimension as a channel to be compatible with the contour format
    const pointMat = cv.matFromArray(1, 1, cnt.type(), offset);
    console.log("pointMat", pointMat.data32S);

    const cntNorm = new cv.Mat(cnt.rows, cnt.cols, cnt.type());
    cv.subtract(cnt, pointMat, cntNorm); <-- my app crashes here with an exception that has only some random number - OpenCV seems to always do that when I'm doing something wrong or it's out of memory
    console.log("ctnorm", cntNorm.data32S);
```

Unfortunately, I cannot find a good example on Python-like matrix operations in the official OpenCV.js documentation on basic data structures. It just shows how to create matrices but does not explain how to perform simple math operations with a matrix and a point-like value.

Also, I'm not sure when I need `new cv.Mat(cnt.rows, cnt.cols, cnt.type());` and when `new cv.Mat()` is enough. The documentation has both but does not answer what is the rule of thumb to use an empty Mat and when it must be configured with row/col/type.

And the log output for `cnt` cols and rows is confusing, it prints 75 rows and 1 col, but the data is `Int32Array(150)`. I found that sometimes the second layer of values are designated by type and not cols/rows. That's confusing. How should we know when to use rows=1,cols=2 and when rows=1,cols=2 and a type with 2 channels?

Comment: It's not working even in Python. Using `pointMat = np.array([1], cnt.dtype)` and `cntNorm = cv2.subtract(cnt, pointMat)` raise an exception `error: (-215:Assertion failed) type2 == CV_64F && (sz2.height == 1 || sz2.height == 4) in function 'cv::arithm_op'`. That means that the type of `pointMat` should be `CV_64F`: `pointMat = np.array([1], np.float64)`... Using `new cv.Mat()` is enough (just try it). I think `rows=1,cols=2` is correct because contour is a two columns matrix with (x,y) pairs.

Comment: @Rotem with rows=1 cols=2 it might break when specifying the same type as the contour, and that is CV_32SC2 (which already has the second dimension, that's why cnt rows=75, cols=1 although there are actually 150 points). But I found a workaround with `const pointMat = cv.matFromArray(1, 1, cnt.type(), offset);  let pointRepeat = new cv.Mat();    cv.repeat(pointMat, cnt.rows, 1, pointRepeat); const cntNorm = new cv.Mat(); cv.subtract(cnt, pointRepeat, cntNorm);` So, the idea is to duplicate the point pair for every row - then both matrices are the same side and OpenCV does not complain anymore.